# Android Layout with Radiobuttons and Edittexts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a bit of trouble with an Android layout I'm currently trying to create.
Something along the lines of this. (The editboxes need to be aligned with the radio buttons, yes.) The problem is that when I actually run this on a phone, it doesn't align up.

Should look something like:

[image]

Currently looks like:

[image]

The XML for this is below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</RadioGroup>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" >


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/radio0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/radio1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/radio2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/radio3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/radio4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Definitely lead me to a design plan that will fit all screen sizes. Have to do a little work around in code since its not in a radiogroup but over the XML layout is exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting some equal heght for all the `RadioButton` and `EditText` instead of `wrap_content`

```
 android:layout_height="30dp"
```

If you feels this is not accurate, I would suggest to create a custom item with `RadioButton` and `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which I would suggest.

- You have different margingTop for EditText and its corresponding RadioButton. Either remove it or make it same.
- RadioGroup is actually a LinearLayout. So, it doesn't take `android:layout_alignLeft` and `android:layout_below`. You can place a RadioButton directly in a RelativeLayout beside a EditText without RadioGroup but would have to handle the toggling in code.